# .NET datetime Millisecond precision issue when converting from string to datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, precision

Hi.
I am trying to convert an incoming datetime value that comes to our system in a string format. It seems that when the precision of milliseconds is higher than 7, the datetime parsing in .NET does not seem to like the value and cannot convert/parse the value. I am a bit stuck on what to do for this? My only current thought is there is a limit on the millisecond size and that anymore precision is not possible? But I want to confirm this is the case rather than assume.

Example:

```
string candidateDateTimeString = "2017-12-08T15:14:38.123456789Z";
if (!success)
        {
            success = DateTime.TryParseExact(trayportDateTimeString, "yyyy-
MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffffff'Z'",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, dateTimeStyles, out dateTime);
        }
```

If I reduce the 'f' values down to just 7, then date time parsing works fine. Is there a limit? Or am I doing something obvious wrong?

Comment: DateTime has precision right up to 7 digits, all subsequent cannot be stored there anyway, that's why such format is not allowed.

Comment: The smallest increment of time that DateTime can store is 100 nanosecond.  That is 7 digits in the fraction.  Instead of just silently ignoring the 8th and subsequent digit it will tell you that you are doing it wrong.  Which ensures that if you ever go back again to a string then you'll get the exact same digits.  Reliable round-tripping is important.  And besides, you can't afford a clock that is that accurate, it is not the kind of equipment you keep in your basement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) docs, 7 is maximum supported digits of second fraction.

Answer (score 2):

Precision of date and time values is more complex than you might think. There are different levels of precision involved:

**Precision of `DateTime`**

`DateTime` stores the number of ticks since 01.01.0001 00:00 as a 64 bit value. One tick is 100 nanoseconds. Since this is the maximum precision that can be stored, it makes no sense to format to a precision higher than that. You can just add as many zeros as you need to represent a higher precision. If you need to represent shorter timespans than 100 nanoseconds, you need to use a different type, such as an `Int64` with a custom tick size.

**Precision of `DateTime.Now`**

When you call `DateTime.Now`, you get a much lower precision than `DateTime` can store. The exact value depends on the system clock, but it is usually in the milliseconds range.

**Precision of `Stopwatch`**

When you measure the time with `Stopwatch`, depending on your system, you might get the time from a high performance clock, which more precise than the clock used for `DateTime.Now`, but still less than 100 nanoseconds. On a system without high performance clock, the precision is the one of the regular system clock.

**Summary**

Unless the value that you are parsing originates from a high precision clock (like an atomic clock), parsing it to the full precision of `DateTime`, makes not much practical sense. And if it comes from such a source, you need to resort to a different data type to represent the value.

Comment: It should read: When you call `DateTime.Now`, you get a much lower _accuracy_ than `DateTime` can store - i.e precision.

Comment: DateTime.Now, under the hood, uses a GetSystemTIme call that's accurate only to 1ms (0.001s). So even though it returns a value with 7 decimal digits of precision, most of them are a lie. For example, if you call it a million times in a tight loop, you'll see that the returned value changes only every millisecond, which could be 10k iterations of a tight loop), and when it does change, the new value jumps by about 1ms.  If you want a high-precision DateTime value, call `new DateTime(Stopwatch.GetTimestamp())`.

Comment: UPDATE: DateTime.UtcNow in netcore6.0 offers up to 100ns accuracy. So that's the full 7 digits after the second. They reworked it. It uses Interop to fetch this.

Comment: N.B. also for netcore: if you want high precision from StopWatch use the value sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, NOT sw.ElapsedMillseconds

`Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
 var x = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;//double - high precision
 var y = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;//long - low precision`

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/9736

Comment: Clarification: Under the hood Dateimte.Utc now (running on up-to-date windows) will use GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime Win API which gives the higher precision.

Answer (score 1):

> Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings